# Implementation of OOPS in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oop

Can you give me some idea about implementation of OOPS in Oracle?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oracle has supported objects since version 8.0 of the database (i.e. over a decade).  However, it wasn't until 9iR2 that Oracle `TYPE` supported user-defined constructors and properly implemented polymorphism.  In 11g they added support for a Java-esque `SUPER()` call.  But Oracle still doesn't support private variables or private methods.

As a consequence, OO programming hasn't really taken off in the Oracle world.  People use Types to define collections in PL/SQL, which are especially useful for [bulk processing](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/collections.htm#CIHIEBJC).  Pipelined functions are also neat, and open up [an interesting little toolset](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=420).

I have used Oracle's object oriented functionality, and if I'm honest there are not many scenarios where it makes sense to choose types over regular PL/SQL.  However, there are some situations where it can be useful.  I have blogged about this at some length.  [Find out more.](http://radiofreetooting.blogspot.com/2006/12/programming-with-oracle-sql-type.html)

edit

As Tuinstoel commented I linked to the wrong article on Adrian's site.  They correctly divined the article I meant to link to, and I have now changed the link accordingly.

Comment: +1 as well - good job of distilling+linking for answer to complex topic

Comment: Maybe this is a better link http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=420 ? It is about pipelined functions, objects, polymorhism and inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

That is a very large subject for a forum question.  See the [Oracle Database Object-Relational Developer's Guide](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28371/toc.htm) for 100s of pages on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have an example of using Oracle objects in combination with inheritance and polymorphism: [link text](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=420) . APC links to another page on this site, also about pipelined functions and objects but without inheritance and polymorphism.

And here is another one: [link text](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:63942113457534#638388600346454279)

(Tom Kyte didn't like it but I post it anyway, I still feel a little sad that the discussion was in the end about commiting in PL/SQL instead of OO programming).