# Oracle deref object from objects table

Tags: oracle, plsql, object-relational-model

I would like to know what is the **best way to get an object from an Oracle object table into a deref variable**.

This is my actual method, lets suppose the type:

```
create or replace TYPE person AS OBJECT (
  dni            VARCHAR2(20),
  nom            VARCHAR2(20),
  MAP MEMBER FUNCTION get_dni RETURN varchar2
);

create or replace TYPE BODY person AS
  MAP MEMBER FUNCTION get_dni RETURN varchar2 IS
  BEGIN
    RETURN dni;
  END;
END;
```

With this objects table:

```
create table partners of person;
```

Then, to get a `person` into a var I do:

```
declare
    a_person person;
begin
    select deref(ref(p)) into a_person
      from partners p 
     where p.dni = 1;
    ...
end;
```

**Is there a more elegant way to get unref object?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that there are no really elegant alternative for your style of table declaration.

Only variant below, but it seems to be less elegant than yours:

```
declare
  a_person person;
begin
  select person(p.dni, p.nom) into a_person
  from partners p 
  where p.dni = 1;
end;
```

I.e. decompose object to fields and construct it back.

But if you declare table with object type field, e.g.

```
create table new_partners (pers person)
```

then access would be much simpler:

```
declare
  a_person person;
begin
  select p.pers into a_person
  from new_partners p 
  where p.pers.dni = 1;
end;
```

[<kbd>SQLFiddle</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9e5d3/7)

Comment: Thanks. Let me wait for alternatives. Middletime, you know if people is using object extensions in non accademicals projects?

Comment: At most cases object extensions used on very limited basis without inheritance and methods, just as custom storage structurea. On this point I agree with [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1504037/232279). Personally for me a main factor which stopping me from object usage at OOP manner is a bad support for changes in data structure in compare with a plain relational tables with packages. Think about adding adding a new field into one of core objects.